# Taylor series and extreme value

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Given the function $f(x)=x^6\ln(1+x^3)$, I need to determine using Taylor's theorem, whether or not $f(x)$ has an extreme value at $x=0$. My hypothesis is that it doesn't have an extreme value there.

I believe this can be proven if, given some arbitrary neighborhood of zero $E:=\vert x - 0 \vert < \ r$, we can show $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x_0 \in E$ ( and $x_0\neq 0 $ ). In other words, no matter how small the interval around zero is, the function is monotonically increasing on that interval, and thus there can't be an extreme value at zero. My idea is to approximate $f$ as a Taylor polynomial, then use the mean value theorem $$f(b)-f(a)=dy=(b-a)f'(x)$$

and show $dy>0$ for all $b,a \in E$. Does this idea work or have I made an error somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Taylor series, you can show that
$$
f(x) \approx x^9 - \frac{x^{12}}{2} + \frac{x^{15}}{3} + \cdots
$$
This is enough to make your plan of showing that $f'(x) > 0$ for $x$ near, but not equal to, $0$. Indeed, $f'(x) \approx 9 x^8$ near $0$. Further, explicit error bounds are easily attainable since this is an alternating series.

But I think it is a good idea to understand the big picture. Morally this indicates that if you were to zoom in very closely, the function behaves essentially like $x^9$ near $0$, and thus doesn't have a max or min at $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the point of this problem is, but I can say Taylor is not a good way to do it. We have $f(x) > 0$ for $x>0$ and $f(x) < 0$ on $(-1,0).$ That's all we need to show $f$ doesn't have an extreme value at $x=0.$